# How to combine dict objects which contain the same key value, and output a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to add dict objects which contain the same key value, and get a list. I have a function and I do:

```
def arizakestirimi_func(self):
    arizatahmin = []
    ...
    record = {} //create a new dict
    record["isyeri"]=key
    record["mekanikarizatahminsuresi"]= arizatahminsüresi
    arizatahmin.append(record);
    ...
    record = {} //create a new dict
    record["isyeri"]=key //key can be same 
    record["elektrikarizatahminsuresi"]= arizatahminsüresi //this is different key value
    arizatahmin.append(record);
    ...
    record = {} //create a new dict
    record["isyeri"]=key //key can be same 
    record["kesintilerarizatahminsuresi"]= arizatahminsüresi //this is different key value

    arizatahmin.append(record);

    #Return value as a HttpResponse.
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'arizaTahminSuresi': arizatahmin},indent=2), content_type="application/json")
```

My output is json like this:

```
{
  "arizaTahminSuresi": [
    {
      "isyeri": "15400005",//The same key
      "mekanikarizatahminsuresi": 38.95637287225691
    },

    {
      "isyeri": "15400005",//The same key
      "elektrikarizatahminsuresi": 427.9069449086019
    },

      "isyeri": "15400005",//The same key
      "kesintilerarizatahminsuresi": 4.882768280126584
    }

  ]
}
```

I want the output to be as follows. How can I do it?

```
{
  "arizaTahminSuresi": [
    {
      "isyeri": "15400005",
      "mekanikarizatahminsuresi": 38.95637287225691
      "elektrikarizatahminsuresi": 427.9069449086019
      "kesintilerarizatahminsuresi": 4.882768280126584
    }   
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `groupby` to get all the matching dicts, then unfy them using `update`, like this:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint

original = {
    "arizaTahminSuresi": [
        {
            "isyeri": "15400005",
            "mekanikarizatahminsuresi": 38.95637287225691
        },
        {
            "isyeri": "15400003",
            "mekanikarizatahminsuresi": 312.05942081303965
        },
        {
            "isyeri": "15400002",
            "mekanikarizatahminsuresi": 773.600387779049
        },
        {
            "isyeri": "15400004",
            "mekanikarizatahminsuresi": 275.25620818317475
        },
        {
            "isyeri": "15400001",
            "mekanikarizatahminsuresi": 9.032135504089638
        },
        {
            "isyeri": "15400004",
            "elektrikarizatahminsuresi": 105.3605215202133
        },
        {
            "isyeri": "15400003",
            "elektrikarizatahminsuresi": 463.8990083193239
        },
        {
            "isyeri": "15400001",
            "elektrikarizatahminsuresi": 49.71052726257949
        },
        {
            "isyeri": "15400005",
            "elektrikarizatahminsuresi": 427.9069449086019
        },
        {
            "isyeri": "15400002",
            "elektrikarizatahminsuresi": 25.78649617892279
        },
        {
            "isyeri": "15400004",
            "kesintilerarizatahminsuresi": 67.41996630760787
        },
        {
            "isyeri": "15400005",
            "kesintilerarizatahminsuresi": 4.882768280126584
        },
        {
            "isyeri": "15400002",
            "kesintilerarizatahminsuresi": 58.96635620693996
        },
        {
            "isyeri": "15400001",
            "kesintilerarizatahminsuresi": 357.28675445627414
        },
        {
            "isyeri": "15400003",
            "kesintilerarizatahminsuresi": 434.16131082294305
        }

    ]
}

grouped_subdicts = groupby(sorted(original["arizaTahminSuresi"], key=itemgetter("isyeri")), itemgetter("isyeri"))

result = []
for k,g in grouped_subdicts:
    d = {}
    for sub_d in g:
        d.update(sub_d)
    result.append(d)

original["arizaTahminSuresi"] = result

pprint(original)
```

Comment: Thanks but when ı do "grouped_subdicts = groupby(original["arizaTahminSuresi"], itemgetter("isyeri"))" ı got  typeerror "string indices must be integers".

Comment: @UYAR.C are you sure your data is as you described in the question? try running my code here: https://ideone.com/t6MPRX , it runs without errors and returns the correct output. If it is slightly different, we can make the adjustments for it to work

Comment: you are right this code work. But ı do original=json.dumps({'arizaTahminSuresi': arizatahmin}, indent=2)                                                                    grouped_subdicts = groupby(original["arizaTahminSuresi"], itemgetter("isyeri")) ı got the same error ı dont why. Also when ı print(original["arizaTahminSuresi"]) ı got the same error.

Comment: @UYAR.C OK now I see when you use `json.dumps` you get a string. you should use it on the final result only after doing all the processing.

Comment: @UYAR.C so just start with `original={'arizaTahminSuresi': arizatahmin}`

Comment: Adam.Er8 thanks ıt ıs working but when ı use more than one key for "isyeri" ı got key error. How can fix it? You can see here: https://ideone.com/wZShOu

Comment: @UYAR.C OK, we have to sort them by the same `itemgetter` before the groupby. edited my answer